# The Role of Acidified Potassium Manganate(VII) in Oxidation of Alcohols

Tags: organic-chemistry, catalysis, organic-oxidation

The chemical equation for the oxidation of ethanol is given as:
$$\ce{C2H5OH + 2[O] -> CH3COOH + H2O}.$$
Acidified potassium manganate (VII) solution $\ce{KMnO4}$ is added as the oxidising agent. My question is how does the $\ce{KMnO4}$ help in the oxidation? My guess is the reaction between acid and $\ce{KMnO4}$ releases oxygen that will be used in the oxidation of alcohol. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You may find the reactions starting from acidified permanganate solution and producing $\ce{HMnO4}$, then this acid being decomposed and producing oxygen atoms, and finally oxydation of ethanol with these oxygen atoms. But this problem is more easily solved by using half-equations, like all redox reactions. You should know this general approach. It gives, with ions of permanganate, instead of $\ce{KMnO4}$  :
$$\ce{MnO4^- + 8 H+ + 5 e- ->  Mn^{2+} + 4 H2O }$$ and $$\ce{C2H5OH + H2O -> CH3COOH + 4 H+ + 4 e-}$$ The only specialty is the high total number of electrons involved, $20$ in total. The sum of these two half-equations gives : $$\ce{4 MnO4^- + 5 C2H5OH + 12 H+ -> 4 Mn^{2+} + 5 CH3COOH + 11 H2O}$$.

Comment: The mechanism involving [O] is specious. 20 electrons is not a problem they are necessary.

Comment: So is that true that the equation of the oxidation of alkene to produce alcohol with KMnO4 is : 2MnO4^- + 6H^+ + 5C2H4 + 2H2O -> 2Mn^2+ + 5C2H4(OH)2

Comment: @Zhang Jin. Your equation produces glycol, which can be considered as a diol.

Comment: Ok got it... so does that means the equation is correct but the product is glycol, not alcohol ?

Comment: Writing an equation does not guarantee a reaction. A strong oxidizing agent such a permanganate will give different products under different conditions. Under acidic conditions with total reduction to Mn++ ethylene would be oxidized to carbon dioxide and water. Cold neutral dilute permanganate will oxidize ethylene to ethylene glycol while being reduced to MnO2. Buy an older edition of Morrison and Boyd and read it cover to cover to get an idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you quote is **not** a chemical equation. It is a symbolic equation stating that an oxidizing chemical is needed to effect oxidation of an alcohol to an acid. A chemical equation shows the reactants and the products and is properly balanced to show the stoichiometry. Ethanol can be oxidized to acetic acid by many different oxidants such as permanganate, $\ce{MnO4-}$ [btw. $\ce{Mn(VII)}$ not $\ce{Mn(IV)}$], dichromate, $\ce{Cr2O7^2-}$, both in acidic solutions, molecular $\ce{O2}$ usually with the help of enzymes as in the conversion of wine into vinegar by microorganisms or the removal of ethanol from our bodies. The mechanisms of these reactions do not involve the formation of oxygen atoms. They involve the transfer of electrons from the alcohol to the oxidizing chemical with the aid of acid and water.

Your homework assignment is to find the reactions of ethanol with permanganate, dichromate and $\ce{O2}$  and to determine the properly balanced equation for each oxidizing agent.

Comment: So like what you have said oxygen atom don't really exist in the reaction, the equation only indicates that an oxidizing chemical is needed and the reactant that involve in the reaction is only water,  ions of permanganate and ethanol. Am I right?

Comment: Write out the balanced chemical equations. That is a minimum of what is involved. A detailed mechanism is needed to determine everything involved.  One is never "right" in understanding anything.